# Iphone WIFI "call home" function?

Tags: iphone, wifi

We're deploying a Wifi hotspot service in some locations via unifi. You have to sign up with your mobile number and get an sms which includes the activation link.

The Problem is:

The iPhone seems to check the connectivity of a WLAN to the internet. So, after you sent your number, and before you clicked on the actvation Link, theres no Internet Connection (Basically it is, but youre not allowed to get outside of the Internal network until activation Link has been clicked).

The Iphone recognizes this and disables the WiFi, because it can't contact his "Testserver" - so you are on 3g again, and the activation Link isn't reachable anymore.

My Question:

Does anybody know to which IP the Iphone tries to connect before it deactivates WiFI?

So i could Whitelist this IP to be reachable without authentication, so the Iphone wouldnt disable Wifi by itself anymore.

I've tried to catch it up via wireshark, but i didnt see anything. :(